# MBP 2012 retina, OSX 10.13.6 - Hardware Self Check not accessible

Tags: macbook-pro, apple-hardware-test

I have noted my MBP (Mac Book Pro) running OSX 10.13.6 seems to have slowed a lot over the last several months.

Holding down the D key as it starts up, one can access the self check hardware test.  There is also an option to hold Opt D to access self check the laptop via an internet connection.

I only get the internet option with just the D key?

If I try the internet option, having no choice, and put in password for my internet connection, I get a error message saying it can not access efi something (should have written what appeared on the screen down), then it froze.

I have previously been able to run the hardware self check on this MBP.

There seems no way for me to access this hardware test function.

Is this normal or unusual?  Any work arounds?

Comment: What Mac model is it? are you using a firmware password? is your keyboard working properly? Have you resetted SMC and NVRAM/PRAM, also check your internal disk in disk utility with first aid (preferably in recovery mode: https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201255). Slowing down is not something that should happen by itself, you must have either installed some program running in the background or maybe your hard drive is running out of space.

Comment: @X_841 Good points:  HD not full. 100GB plus available.  NVRAM/PRAM reset, keyboard is fine, not using a firmware password (or I have not set one up), As mentioned MBP 2012 Retina. No recent installed programs.  SMC?

Comment: Key issue is not being able to access the hardware test. How does that come about? That is what I am trying to solve. Hardware test may indicate an issue, having eliminated pretty much everything else. Eg thermal past failing issue reducing performance, or something else.